# Bash: handling "[[ statement ]] || echo problem found ; exit 1" logic

Tags: bash, scripting, control-flow

In the statement in the title, there is a problem that even if the statement is true, it will still exit with status 1 because, as I understand it:

```
[[ statement ]] || echo problem found ; exit 1
```

Evaluates to if the statement is false, echo problem found.  Exit with status 1.  Even if the statement evaluates true, the exit 1 still happens because it is separate.  I thought to fix this by running it in a subshell like so:

```
[[ statement ]] || (echo problem found ; exit 1)
```

This seems to do what I want, but is it an acceptable way to handle this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use

```
[[ statement ]] || { echo problem found ; exit 1; }
```

The difference is that the brace syntax doesn't create a subshell, which means the `exit 1` applies to the current shell.  If you use `(exit 1)` the subshell exits but the current shell continues running.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use syntax like this :

```
[[ statement ]] || { echo problem found ; exit 1; }
```

and more accurate send standard error

```
[[ statement ]] || { echo >&2 "problem found"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: Thanks! More notes for beginners: 1) You __must__ leave one whitespace after both the opening and closing brace. 2) Don't forget the __semicolon__ after the last statement! If you do, you will get a very pointless (and misleading) error message: ''unexpected end of file'' (?!?)

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to be clever. Remember that [debugging is twice as hard as writing](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan), so when you're writing a program, be only half as clever as you can be.

```
if ! [[ statement ]]; then
  echo problem found
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: +1 For the quote. I don't know why one-liners are so popular on SE and in general, as most of them are buggy and hard to understand/read.